# Rstats, How to optimize read_csv with a large numbers of files

Tags: r

I have a folder of csv files, I am trying to to read all those files using read_csv, it works well with 12 files but after that I got this error

r: cannot allocate vector of size 2.8 Mb

here is a link to the csv files, I manually download the files and unzip it
http://nemweb.com.au/Reports/Archive/Daily_Reports/

```r
library(tidyverse)
data_path <- "C:/Users/csv2/"   # path to the data
files <- dir(data_path, pattern = "*.CSV") # get file names

data <- files %>%
  # read in all the files, appending the path before the filename
  map(~ read_csv(file.path(data_path, .),col_types = cols_only(DISPATCH = col_guess(),
                                                               '1'=col_character(),
                                                               SETTLEMENTDATE = col_character(),
                                                               INTERVENTION = col_character(),
                                                               CASESUBTYPE = col_character(),
                                                               SOLUTIONSTATUS = col_character(),
                                                               NONPHYSICALLOSSES = col_character()),
                                                               skip = 1)) %>% 
  reduce(rbind)
data = rename(data,aemo='1')
data = filter(data,aemo=='2')
data = filter(data,DISPATCH=='TREGION' | DISPATCH=='DREGION' | DISPATCH=='DUNIT' | DISPATCH=='TUNIT')
```

I tried with fread, but it does not like the format as it has different numbers of headers

Comment: "Cannot allocate vector" means your machine is out of memory.

Comment: All the zip files together seem to occupy 15~20 GB. You might not have enough memory

Comment: I'd still suggest using `data.table::fread()`. That is throws an error on different number of headers can probably be addressed using `fill = NA` or use the `select`-argument, or something similar... Furthermore, using `fread()`, you can easily use the `cmd`-argument of `fread()` to filter data **before** loading it into R (using command `grep` on linux, or `findstr` on windows). Not only speeding up the process, but also making the process (much) more memory efficient by only loading the lines you need (in stead of filtering them out after loading).

Comment: thanks for your comment, fill=NA, and select did help, fread stop reading when he finds extra columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @wimpel correctly states above, use `data.table`. It is very well known for its low consumption of computer resources, as well as, one of the fastest.

Please, refer to this example in GitHub: https://github.com/f0nzie/fread-benchmarks-rsuite.

What you will notice immediately is that for the same size of input files being read, `fread` consumes less than a 1/10 of RAM than doing it with `r-base` or `tidyverse`.

[image]